# How can I correct punctuation when I am typing?

Tags: keyboard

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my 7 year old windows laptop. It works great except that when I am typing the punctuation keys are wrong. For example I need to type  ~ for @.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Are you using the wrong keyboard layout for your region? Look in `system settings` then `keyboard` then `input sources`. It may be slightly different for you, as I have Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you have the wrong keyboard-layout.

You can change that by running

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

in a terminal. Then you can just follow the instructions on the screen.

Comment: there should be a indicator for that showing somethink like `De` or `En`.